# What is, and why, "byte[ ] + number" in this IDA pseudocode?

Tags: ida, assembly, decompilation, c++, c

This is a decompile of an `.so` file, so it originated from C or C++. Can you kindly try to explain to me what this does?

How would one rewrite this into readable code? I don't mind any programming language.

The loop below is strange: I think it is a `for` loop but it uses a byte during checking... oh no, this is so wrong. There is one thing I am sure, in the function crackMe the `*two` is actually a byte array.

And what about the `++keep`? and `(two++)[1]`? Can byte minus byte result in `(_BYTE *)(two - newByte)`?

This is surely a short code but so much to analyse.

```
unsigned __int8 *__fastcall crackMe(unsigned __int8 *i, _BYTE *two)
{
  _BYTE *newByte; 
  int flag; 
  int rule; 
  _BYTE *rule2; 
  unsigned __int8 *result; 
  int currentNumCopy; 
  int currentNum; 
  int keep; 
  int forCompare; 
  int isFinal; 

  newByte = two + 1;
  flag = (unsigned __int8)*two;
  if ( !*two )
    return i;
  do
    rule = (unsigned __int8)(two++)[1];
  while ( rule );
  rule2 = (_BYTE *)(two - newByte);
  while ( 1 )
  {
    result = i;
    currentNum = *i++;
    currentNumCopy = currentNum;
    if ( !currentNum )
      break;
    if ( currentNumCopy == flag)
    {
      if ( !rule2 )
        return result;
      keep = 0;
      while ( 1 )
      {
        forCompare = (unsigned __int8)newByte[keep];
        isFinal = result[keep + 1];
        if ( !result[keep + 1] || isFinal != forCompare )
          break;
        if ( rule2 == (_BYTE *)++keep )
          return result;
      }
      if ( isFinal == forCompare )
        return result;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My attempt to rewrite it in Java, you can rewrite it in C or C++ or C# or Python or any language you prefer:

```
        byte[] newByte;
        int flag;
        int rule; 
        byte rule2; 
        int result;
        int currentNumCopy; 
        int keep; 
        int forCompare; 
        int isFinal; 

        newByte = two;
        newByte[two.length + 1] = 1; //I am confused, did it convert array to integer then add 1 or add 1 to the end of array?

        ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(two); // big-endian by default
        flag = wrapped.getInt();
        for (int currentNum = 0; currentNumCopy == flag; currentNum++) {
        ??? rule = ?
```

Comment: decompilation is guesswork and there may be wrong guesses post the relevant assembly too for someone to take a shot

Comment: here u go https://i.ibb.co/FXwXFhv/asm.png @blabb

Comment: it just a function to return a string, correct me if I'm wrong I didn't see it hook any other functions

Comment: I guess ida don't know the data type

Comment: @ Gin May your link says image not found :( post the disassembly as text here yes from a fleet look it appears it checks two string and returns a,b,or 0  (probably a strcmp function  you can also use some emulators like oaksim , visual arm to emulate the code

Comment: It is obfuscated using ollvm, that's why I deleted it. I am stucked as there are no plugin for IDA to clean it :( really hope there's someone capable to port it to python script. I saw a c++ plugin but it's not compatible with ida 6.8 or 7.0 https://www.hexblog.com/?p=1248

Answer (score -1):

I guess `newByte[two.length + 1] = 1;` look like iterate some value in variable `two`